# Stash output=yes vs get

Tags: stash

Is there any difference in processing/speed in using Stash exp:stash:set with output=yes vs. using Stash to set and then outputting via exp:stash:get? For example:

```
OPTION 1:
{exp:stash:set name="client_age" 
    save="yes"
    output="yes"
    refresh="no"
    trim="yes" 
    parse_tags="yes"
    parse_conditionals="yes" 
    parse_depth="2"
    scope="user"
}
    {exp:channel:entries channel=".....}
        {PLUGIN}{content}{/PLUGIN}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}

VERSUS OPTION 2:
{exp:stash:set name="client_age" 
    save="yes"
    refresh="no"
    trim="yes" 
    parse_tags="yes"
    parse_conditionals="yes" 
    parse_depth="2"
    scope="user"
}
    {exp:channel:entries channel=".....}
        {PLUGIN}{content}{/PLUGIN}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:stash:get name="client_age" scope="user"}
```

Comment: I think it's a good question for pure curiosity, but why would you use option 1 with Stash if you're not needing to 'get' it later?

Comment: Option 1 is being saved to the database as well as 2, so I don't want to run the inner content for the duration it's saved. I'm hoping to see if they're efficiently the same, and both pull from the stash table once the variable has been written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 will be a tiny bit quicker, since EE only needs to process one tag. It's a good approach for caching arbitrary chunks of template code.

Unless you really do need to have a personalised cached item for *every* visitor to your site I would suggest you use `scope="site"`.

Comment: Thanks Mark! This was for a variable only shown to the individual logged in user (age I think).